# What's the best way to add a C include path when using `bundle install`?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

As background, I have extensive knowledge of software build systems, Unix (I'm using Debian 11 in this instance) and Python environments, but almost no knowledge of modern Ruby environments.

I'm wanting to write a post in a friend's blog built with Jekyll and so am trying to get his blog building in development mode on my system. I'm wanting to minimise the amount of Ruby stuff I bring in using system packages, so I'm using `bundle install --path vendor/bundle` to set up the project dependencies, which include the `rmagick` gem.

I've installed the `libmagickcore-6.q16-dev` package, which gives me `/usr/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/MagickWand.h`. However, bundler is unable to install the RMagick 2.16.0 gem.

Looking in `vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/rmagick-2.16.0/mkmf.log`, this seems to be the failure:

```
have_header: checking for wand/MagickWand.h... -------------------- no
                                                                                
"x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -E -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.7.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.7.0 -I.      conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:3:10: fatal error: wand/MagickWand.h: No such file or directory      
    3 | #include <wand/MagickWand.h>                                            
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Without doing extensive further investigation, I'm guessing that this is due to the include path being incorrect. This kind of hints at the RMagick gem being broken, since `pkg-config` does supply this:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags MagickCore
-fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu//ImageMagick-6 -I/usr/include/ImageMagick-6
```

I'm not able to upgrade the Gems that he's using, nor even easily test that any changes I might make on my system work on the systems he's using. So to work around this I'd like to get  `bundle` to add `-I /usr/include/ImageMagick-6` (or do the moral equivalent).

What's the best way to make this happen? I don't see a `bundle` command line option for this. Perhaps there's an environment variable I can set?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the RMagick was using the correct include paths, though these were not displayed in the `mkmf.log` file above. The issue was that I actually didn't have the include file itself, despite `pkg-config --cflags MagickCore` giving the path to the `wand/` subdirectory.

I'd installed the Debian 11 package `libmagickcore-6.q16-dev`, which supplies `MagickCore.pc`, based on an earlier  error indicating that `pkg-config MagickCore` was failing. However, the `RMagic` package actually requires a different library/set of headers, supplied by the `libmagickwand-6.q16-dev` package. After installing that, `bundle` appeared to build the RMagick gem without difficulty.

While debugging this I did come across a [list of GCC environment variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html), and it seems as if the `C_INCLUDE_PATH` one mentioned there might solve the original problem I'd posted above. However, I've no easy way of testing this right now.